# How do I make a donut in Kotlin Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my main activity I call the donut routine with the following parameters:

```
setContent {
    Row() {
        donut(_size = 100.dp, _padding = 10.dp)
    }
}
```

And here is the donut function:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun donut(_size: Dp = 120.dp, _padding: Dp = 5.dp) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(_size)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(Color.Green)
        .padding(_padding)
        .clip(CircleShape)
        .background(Color.Red))
}
```

I know the donut function works but it won't display in preview.  When trying to see a preview I get the following message: Unable to find @Preview 'com.pelicancolder.chapter1_03.MainActivity.donut'

However I don't understand why compose can't find the donut function.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967310/is-it-possible-to-call-a-donut-routine-within-the-mainactivity-using-different-p/74968915#74968915),
The `@Preview` has to be applied to a function without parameters.
Remove the `@Preview` from your `donut` function and add another function as below

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewDonut() {
    donut()
}
```

You can also make the new function private should you wish.